# An unexpected UNDERSCORE appearing

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I was working with w3.css and font awesome icons. I created two links and used `check` and `time` icons for them. The first link (icon) is showing and underscore `_` next to it. But it is not in the code. I have tried changing the icon but it is still there. I inspected it in Firefox and the underscore is part of `<a></a>` and not the icon. Can you help resolve this problem?

Here is a screenshot:[image]

Here is the code:

```
<td>
            <a href="ajaxAction.php?aid=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-check w3-text-green w3-hover-green"></i>
            </a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="ajaxAction.php?unid=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-times w3-text-red w3-hover-red"></i>
            </a>
</td>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that's the `text-decoration` style (underline) of the link.  try `a, a:hover {text-decoration:none;}` in your css - just make it more specific if you don't want to remove the underline from all your links...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The a link is underlined by default and contains the icon and empty spillover.

Add 
 `text-decoration: none;` to the links to prevent the default underscore style on links.

EDIT: Full Example(without icons):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body class="w3-container">

<table>
<tr><td>
            <a href="ajaxAction.php?aid=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-check w3-text-green w3-hover-green"></i>
            </a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="ajaxAction.php?unid=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-times w3-text-red w3-hover-red"></i>
            </a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
            <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="ajaxAction.php?aid=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-check w3-text-green w3-hover-green">_</i>
            </a>
            &nbsp;
            <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="ajaxAction.php?unid=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-times w3-text-red w3-hover-red">_</i>
            </a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
            <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="ajaxAction.php?aid=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-check w3-text-green w3-hover-green">_</i>
            </a>
            &nbsp;
            <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="ajaxAction.php?unid=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-times w3-text-red w3-hover-red">_</i>
            </a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Using `text-decoration: none;` solved the issue. I wonder why it was only happening to this link only? I bet it wasn't there a few hours ago. Anyway, thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

apply hover in style tag separately then check it or in separate CSS file and include it and Remove &nbsp  user css instead

```html
<style>
a:hover {
color: red;
}
</style>
<td>
            <a href="ajaxAction.php?aid=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">
              
            </a>
            
            <a href="ajaxAction.php?unid=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">
                
            </a>
</td>
```